# Get List Column names C#

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server, csom

I want to Iterate through all List items and its columns names without hard coding the columns names.

I only need columns names visible in Sharepoint list settings. [image]

but below code is giving me too many columns. How can I filter it to show only above columns?

```
CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
        ListItemCollection items = Discussions.GetItems(query);

        context.Load(Discussions.Fields);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var f in Discussions.Fields)
    {
        if (!f.Hidden && !f.CanBeDeleted)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", f.Title, f.InternalName, f.Hidden, f.CanBeDeleted);                
    }
```

Comment: So you need all the items having discussion as content type and then show all the fields associated with that item which are used in Discussion?

Comment: yes. everything that is shown in List settings page. There more columns for Message content type also

Comment: you always need default content type or you need to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see you are already filtering on the Hidden and CanBeDeleted properties.

There are some others you should consider filtering on too such as AllowDeletion, CanBeDisplayedInEditForm, CanToggleHidden, ReadOnlyField, Sealed etc.

In particular, a field being both ReadOnlyField and Sealed would indicate that it is a system field that you probably don't want to display.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the below code (It's not optimized but will work for you):

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Url))
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Test"];
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = @"<Where>
                              <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>
                                <Value Type='Computed'>Discussion</Value>
                              </Eq>
                            </Where>";
                SPListItemCollection itmColl = list.GetItems(query);
                SPContentTypeCollection ctColl = list.ContentTypes;
                SPContentType ct = ctColl["Discussion"];

                SPFieldCollection ctFields = ct.Fields;
                SPFieldCollection desiredFields = null;
                if (itmColl.Count > 0)
                {
                    SPListItem itm = itmColl[0];
                    SPFieldCollection itmFieldColl = itm.Fields;
                    foreach (SPField field in itmFieldColl)
                    {
                        if (ctFields.Contains(field.Id))
                        {
                            //You'll have all the fields with the particular content type in desiredFields.
                            desiredFields.Add(field);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can later use `desiredFields` to find internal names etc for all the fields.

The above answer worked to find the fields used in the list for a particular content type.
To find all the fields in the list. we can use the below code:

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(web.Url))
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Test"];
                SPFieldCollection listFields = list.Fields;
                    foreach (SPField field in listFields)
                    {
                        string internalName = field.InternalName;
                    }
             }
```

Comment: I dont need field of just 1 2 contents types.. I need all fields from current LIST

Comment: itmFieldColl will have all the fields. or you can use SPFieldCollection listFields = list.Fields;

Comment: This is what I posted in question. it is returning lots of fields. There are around 30 Fields in Sharepoint List settings page. but list.Fields is returning 100+ fields

Comment: @Muhammadzaighum..in your question you are using discussion.fields which is in turn returning all the fields for the discussion content type.

Comment: discussion is variable name. which points to lists. sorry for this confusion.

Comment: What extra columns is it returning? columns from the content type which aren't used? Currently I am not able to understand the question then. Sorry